# Aws-vault: Failed to get credentials - InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services

When I use

```
aws-vault exec --no-session --debug role_name
```

I get:

```
2020/06/09 13:57:13 [keyring] Found item "aws-vault (default)"
aws-vault: error: exec: Failed to get credentials for role_name: InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
        status code: 403, request id: 05bf31bd-091e-4f18-83c5-7add3e1bccb8
```

First of all I thought about incorrect password, but when tried to put an incorrect password purposely, Mac Os ask again for the correct password.

I have the `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials` with the correct setup.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Had the same error after rotating AWS credentials.
Deleted `~/Library/Keychains/aws-vault.keychain-db` and executed `aws-vault add default` which created a new keychain and aws-vault started working again.

If you are on MacOS, you can probably edit the keychain directly.

Comment: On Windows, you need to find the aws-vault entry in the credentials manager and delete it. Afterwards, add credentials again to aws-vault as mentionend.

Comment: For me it turned out to be that the underlying api key was inactive. Which I had to make active again in aws console. Which I found out after deleting the keychain db and then adding my default profile.

Comment: This won't work if your profile name is not "default". Mine was "master", and before I could do anything, I needed to comment out the following line in my .aws/config file: `source_profile=master` and then UNcomment it after I re-added my profile using `aws-vault add  master`. Regardless, this did NOT fix the issue for me.